# jQuery function call in a container

Tags: jquery, html, function, call

So I've this:

```
    function pageSwap(menuPont){   
    $(".content").fadeOut("1000",function(){
            $(".content").load(menuPont, function(){
                $(".content").fadeIn("5000");
            });       
    });
}
```

on index.php, and also this

```
    $(".content").ready(function(){pageSwap('main.html')});
```

Both work and stuff, but my problem is, that I need to call a pageSwap('other.html') 

**IN THE  .content div,** link style.

I couldn't get this working, so please help me. :[

Comment: What do you mean with 'In the .content div'?

Comment: What exactly did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: I need to call the pageSwap function (that's located in index.php) from an included file which is in the .container div. :D

I tried onclick = "function(){ pageSwap blah", copying the function, etc.. Not working. :(

Comment: I am also confused at what the problem is here

Comment: http://huwil.hu Check out the source code. You'll may find your answer. :D I want to call the function in the "Üdvözöljük honlapunkon" area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what want to accomplish, but I assume that you want to call pageSwap('other.html'), when someone clicks on the .content div?

```
$(function(){
  pageSwap('main.html');
  $('.content').click(function(){
    pageSwap('other.html');
  }
});
```

UPDATED with the solution from the comments:
To call the pageSwap('other.html') when clicking on a link within the container, put the function call into the href:

```
<a href="javascript:pageSwap('other.html');">my link</a>
```

Comment: Almost, I want to perform the swap when someone clicks on a link in the container div, but it's a problem, because the container div contains a page INCLUDED by jQuery.

Comment: What about adding the function call to the href of the link? <a href="javascript:pageSwap('other.html');">my link</a>. Does that work?

Comment: Beautiful!  Exactly what I was looking for.